# typescript dependency injection framework

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection

I am writing a simple library using TypeScript (not using angular).  I need to use a DI framework in this library.  I checked out the DI framework in Angular2, but this seems like an overkill and I need to wrap my whole library in an Angular module which I don't want to do.

Comment: https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS

Answer (score 3):

I don't use DI in TypeScript/ES6 for production (yet) because they are not yet finalized.

For experimenting, I used [needlepoint](https://github.com/andrewmunsell/needlepoint) which was at the time I was using ES6.

But for typescript, [typescript-ioc](https://github.com/thiagobustamante/typescript-ioc) looks like it's a better candidate. It has both IOC and DI.

Answer (score -1):

[Dime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@coined/dime) is a simple dependency injection library that I made. It is inspired by Angular's dependency injection system. It is still in development, so there might be some bugs. You can find more information on the [wiki](https://github.com/Anut-py/dime/wiki).

Here is a simple example of it in use:

```
import { ItemsService } from './items-service'; // ItemsService is an interface
import { Inject } from '@coined/dime';

class ItemsWidget {
    @Inject()
    private itemsService: ItemsService;

    render() {
        this.itemsService.getItems().subscribe(items => {
            // ...
        })
    }
}

// Setup
const appPackage = new Package("App", {
    token: "itemsService",
    provideClass: AmazonItemsService // AmazonItemsService implements ItemsService
});

Dime.mountPackages(appPackage);

// Display the widget
const widget = new ItemsWidget();
widget.render();
```

You might have to disable strict property initializers in `tsconfig.json` for this to work.